# Bitbucket pipelines cache keys?

Tags: caching, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Do pipelines cache system support cache keys?

In my project build process, I have many assets to be built by web pack. Resulting assets are copied to public/build directory. That process can take several minutes to complete.

So I would like to generate a hash of the assets directory content (the one from which web pack is building) and store a cache with for example "assets-{assets-directory-hash}" as a key and the public/build directory as a cache container.

Then in a next build if assets directory content hash didn't change it would mean that assets didn't change, and I could skip web pack building step, restore public/build directory from the cache, and save few minutes of the entire build as a result. If hash did change, then I would run web pack as usual, and store cache with a new key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, last year, Bitbucket pipelines introduced cache keys:

[Announcement](https://bitbucket.org/blog/announcing-smarter-caches-bitbucket-pipelines)

> Today we are announcing the option to add cache keys to your Pipelines cache definitions. Cache keys provide a way to uniquely identify versions of a cache based on a set of files in your repository. The typical use case would be to define a cache key based on files that define a project's dependencies. When dependencies are updated, the hash of the key files also updates and Pipelines will be able to generate a unique cache version for subsequent builds. As multiple cache versions are able to be retained, future builds using either the old or new dependency set will have a unique cache version to reuse.

[Documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-and-service-container-definitions/#Key)